# How to use order by query both with current table column and relationship table column in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i am trying to fetch record with order by query but situation is this that i have to use order by both on current table column and relationship  table column in laravel  . I tried this

```
 $consignments = Consignment::where('delivery_run_id', $id)->whereIn('status', [
            'In Warehouse',
            'With On Forwarder',
            'In Transit (Warehouse->Delivery)',
            'Awaiting Pickup'
        ])->with(['consignment_run_sheet' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('run_sheet_id');
        }])->orderBy('delivery_date', 'DESC')->get();
        $deliveryRuns = DeliveryRun::all();
```

How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will order just the relation items in this way. solution is use subquery or joins. useing Subquery is like this if assume the modal for consignment_run_sheet relation is ConsignmentRunSheet and the relation is belongsTo:

```
 $consignments = Consignment::where('delivery_run_id', $id)->whereIn('status', [
            'In Warehouse',
            'With On Forwarder',
            'In Transit (Warehouse->Delivery)',
            'Awaiting Pickup'
        ])->with('consignment_run_sheet')
        ->orderBy(ConsignmentRunSheet::select('delivery_date')
                  ->whereColumn('consignments.id', 'consignment_run_sheet.consignment_id'), 'DESC')
        ->get()
```

source:
https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel

Comment: actually delivery date is column of Consignment table

Comment: @webPakistan ok put whatever column you wanna orderby in ConsignmentRunSheet model