# How can I get the average of a relationship and then orderBy it in Laravel 7.x?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table named `students` and a table named `scores`.

The primary key of the `students` table is `id`.
The table `scores` has a foreign key `student_id` to `students.id`
The table `scores` also has many fields, two of them are `score` and `year`, indicating the value of score and which year did the student got this score.

In a year, a student got many scores. I want to get their average score and rank the students' average score in a specific year.

The model "Student" has a relationship:

```php
    class Student extends Model
    {
        public function scores()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
        }
    }
```

I've tried:
In Student Model,

```php
    class Student extends Model
    {
        public function average_score()
        {
            return $this->scores()
                ->selectRaw('avg(score) as score, student_id')
                ->groupBy('student_id');
        }
    }
```

In StudentCtrl,

```php
    // Select only the student’s scores in a specific year
    $yearQuery = function($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where('year', '=', $request->year);
    };
    
    $list = Student::select('id', 'name')
                     ->with(['average_score' => $yearQuery])
                     ->orderBy('average_score') // <-- If I delete this it works
                     ->paginate(15);
```

It failed with: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'average_score' in 'order clause'

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the raw sql

Comment: Try using ->having() instead of ->with()

Comment: `with` produces a second SQL query executed after the first one. You can't sort the first one by the result of the second one. I suggest a join

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62816609/7908390 you have to subquery or join it for this kind of orderBy.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we are going to leverage [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map), [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby), [avg()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-avg), [sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby)

```
$response = []; // we'll store our final response here

$students = Student::select('id', 'name')->with('scores')->limit(15)->get();

$students->map(function ($student) {
    
    // groupBy student's each score by year
    return $student->scores->groupBy('year')->map(function ($score, $year) use ($student) {
        
       // create new array for simplicity
        $score = [
            'student_id' => $student->id,
            'student_name' => $student->name,
            'average_score' => $score->avg('score'),
            'year' => $year,
        ];
        return $score;

    })->toArray();
})->map(function($lists) use(&$response) {
    
    // groupBy students with each year
    collect($lists)->each(function($list) use(&$response){
        $response[$list['year']][] = collect($list)->forget('year')->toArray();
    });

})->toArray();

dd(collect($response)->map(function($list){
    return collect($list)->sortBy('average_score')->all(); // you sort here
})->all());
```

**sample** response

```
array:3 [
  2016 => array:2 [
    1 => array:3 [
      "student_id" => 2
      "student_name" => "Adam"
      "average_score" => 30
    ]
    0 => array:3 [
      "student_id" => 1
      "student_name" => "John"
      "average_score" => 37.5
    ]
  ]
  2017 => array:3 [
    1 => array:3 [
      "student_id" => 2
      "student_name" => "Adam"
      "average_score" => 50
    ]
    0 => array:3 [
      "student_id" => 1
      "student_name" => "John"
      "average_score" => 70
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "student_id" => 3
      "student_name" => "Tony"
      "average_score" => 80
    ]
  ]
  2018 => array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "student_id" => 3
      "student_name" => "Tony"
      "average_score" => 100
    ]
  ]
]
```

Keep me posted in the comments below. Cheers!

Comment: Wow, this is really elegant, thank you! But I ended up using SQL statements because it was much shorter...